# checking for null in lambda expression - linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datatables

I am attempting to write an expression for an advanced search.  However, I need to check if each property is `null`, otherwise an error will be thrown.

I have included the expression without the null checking below.

The result is output using jQuery dataTables.

```
filteredPeople = unitOfWork.PeopleRepository.Get().Where(c =>
   IdSearchable && c.personID.ToString().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
   || surnameSearchable && c.Surname.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
   || firstNameSearchable && c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
   || genderSearchable && c.Gender.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
));
```

Comment: So what have you tried to check for null? (And given the combinations of && and || you've got there, I'd start explicitly bracketing them...)

Comment: Which properties do you mean to check, and what will you do if they are null? note that the `c.Surname` etc will presumably be handled by an ORM via SQL, so aren't actually tested in C# code. Or is this all LINQ-to-Objects?

Comment: @jc99 observation: since you're coming here to ask for help, it would be to your advantage to answer questions asking for necessary context for *providing* the correct information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below, I basically wrapped all your individual conditional checks inside brackets to further aid both readability and to make sure you don't get any weird results with the compilers interpretation of that *huge* logic.

```
filteredPeople = unitOfWork.PeopleRepository.Get()
                .Where(c => (IdSearchable
                        && c.personID != null
                        && c.personID.ToString().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()))
                    || (surnameSearchable 
                        && c.Surname != null
                        && c.Surname.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()))
                    || (firstNameSearchable 
                        && c.FirstName != null
                        && c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()))
                    || (genderSearchable 
                        && c.Gender != null
                        && c.Gender.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
filteredPeople = unitOfWork.PeopleRepository.Get()
                .Where(c => (IdSearchable
                     && c.personID != null
                     && c.personID.ToString().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()))
                   ||
                     ....
```

From **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

Comment: Personally, I would expect this PeopleRepository.Get() to be using some kind of ORM tooling, in which case this isn't actually going to be executing as .NET *anyway*; I wonder if this is only an issue with a testing mock